# Change date in URL in python for request

Tags: python, json, api, finance

I want to request different data from an API I need to change the date in each request, which I'm thinking to do with a for loop or counter on the day/months, passing that data to the variables below and then append the whole URL. Example below

The api only retrieves the data of the specified time: I have tried appending strs and ints which gives me the result I want, but I just read python can't handle values like 03 for months, days. This would mean I could not request data and just get an error. I tried making it a str but then making it int make it a variable could be a possibility, I am thinking right or am I just ignoring a much simpler way of doing this?

```
url = "https://fxmarketapi.com/apitimeseries?api_key=f_iGO&currency=USDJPY&start_date=2020-01-01&end_date=2020-3-20&format=ohlc"

init_url = "https://fxmarketapi.com/apitimeseries?api_key=f_iGO&currency="
currency = "USDJPY"
#start date
initstart = "&start_date="
start_day = 23
start_month = 03
start_year = 2020
start_date = ('&s%d-%d-%d' % (start_day, start_month, start_year))
#end date
initend = "&end_date="
end_day = 24
end_month = 03
end_year = 2020
end_date = ('&%d-%d-%d' % (end_day, end_month, end_year))
#format of data
format = "&format=ohlc"

date = ('"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s"' % (init_url, currency, initstart, start_date, initend,end_date, format))
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of the datetime module in python.

```
   import datetime

   date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
   str_date = date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) explaining the ways in which you can format date.